# Can't open a .chm file from a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, chm

I am trying to open a .chm file from a batch file.

The batch file has only this text in it :

```
echo off
start "S:\G.T.T\GTT-Vandemecum\Help Danny\GTT.chm"
```

If I run the batch file, the commandline opens but nothing further happens.
If I copy paste `S:\G.T.T\GTT-Vandemecum\Help Danny\GTT.chm` in `start menu/run` then it does works.
If I make a shortcut with target `"S:\G.T.T\GTT-Vandemecum\Help Danny\GTT.chm"` then it also works.

So the command works everywhere, except from a batch file.
What am I doing wrong here ?

It might also be important to know that when I start it from the shortcut, or `start menu/run`I always get a dialog

> We can't verify who created this file. Are you sure you want to open this file ?

I am using Windows 7

EDIT
My problem is not the dialog, my problem is that nothing happens when I open the chm file from a batch file

Comment: Right-click the .chm file in Explorer and tick "Unblock".  If you trust where it came from, usually a web server or email.

Comment: @HansPassant The file is on a shared drive, if I right click it there is no "unblock" option

Comment: Consider asking at superuser.com what you need to do to let the OS trust the "shared drive".  Be sure to provide details about that drive.

Comment: @HansPassant See my edit in my question at the bottom. The dialog is not my problem (I think), my problem is that nothing happens at all when opening it from a batchfile. I dont mind the dialog

Comment: Do not assume that a .bat file will ever open an "are you sure" dialog.  Use %errorlevel% in the .bat file to detect that the command failed.

Comment: @HansPassant OK you could be on to something I will try that out, thanks

Comment: The `Start` command is probably seeing your doublequoted string as a title. Try adding an empty title first, `start "" "S:\G.T.T\GTT-Vandemecum\Help Danny\GTT.chm"`.

Comment: @Compo YES that did the trick, thank you very much. If you put this as answer I will accept it

Comment: _"So the command works everywhere, except from a batch file"_. If the command does not work from a Batch file, then it doesn't work from the command-line either. The problem is not the Batch file, but the _command_ you are using in the Batch file... Try removing the `start` part that does _not_ appear in the other two working examples.

Comment: @Aacini Yes my command was not correct, as already answered by Compo, see his answer

Comment: Yes. I saw Compo's answer. I wanted to note that you said you used _the same command_ in three cases and in one of them it doesn't works, but this is not true: the "command" does not work when you add `start` to it, so I suggest you to use _the same command_ in the Batch file (with no `start` part). Did you tested it? In other words: Compo's answer not explain why the other two cases works (as you described in the question).

Comment: @Aacini Yes I did test it without the `start` in the batch file, it had the same result, nothing happend. I also wrote in my question the exact commands I used in the batch file and in the shortcut and run menu, so it was clear that the last 2 are missing the start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Start` command is probably seeing your doublequoted string as a `title`, enter `Start /?` at the command prompt for its usage information.

Try adding an empty title first:

```bat
@Echo Off
Start "" "S:\G.T.T\GTT-Vandemecum\Help Danny\GTT.chm"
```